# Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH vscode mac

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-code

Firstly, I want to apologize if this question is related to the other solutions that I found, but I spent many hours on fixing the problem and I cannot, for the life of me, find out why I keep getting this error "Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH". I've seen solutions to this problem, but only for Windows OS, not mac. Can someone please help?

Comment: Is 'node' on your path? If you open the terminal and type 'node', does it start node?

Comment: I get a 'node: command not found' when I type node in the terminal.

Comment: Then you probably don't have node installed. It needs to be installed and on the path, for vscode to find it.